# Typescript access object key dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have Theme.ts file like below

```
export default {
  COLORS: {
    DEFAULT: '#172B4D',
    PRIMARY: '#5E72E4',
    SECONDARY: '#F7FAFC',
  }
};
```

In my button component I import above theme file like this --> `import argonTheme from "../constants/Theme";`

In my button component I want to get access to that color dynamically like this

```
 const { small, shadowless, children, color, style, fontSize } = props;
 const colorStyle = color && argonTheme.COLORS[color.toUpperCase()];
```

This line gives me typescript error --> `const colorStyle = color && argonTheme.COLORS[color.toUpperCase()];`

This is the error I'm getting

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ DEFAULT: string; PRIMARY: string; SECONDARY: string ...
```

How can I write this line in typescript ?

```
const colorStyle = color && argonTheme.COLORS[color.toUpperCase()];
```

Comment: Not related but I'd `export const COLOR` instead of an unnamed default object

Comment: Could you add the typings for your `props`. TS is complaining that `color` is implicitely *(not even explicitely)* typed as `any`

Comment: An alternative solution is to use `as keyof typeof` like so: `argonTheme.COLORS[color.toUpperCase() as keyof typeof argonTheme.COLORS]`. Not encouraged, but probably good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a type for the `COLORS` object:

```js
// Theme.ts
const COLORS: Record<string, string> =  {
  DEFAULT: '#172B4D',
  PRIMARY: '#5E72E4',
  SECONDARY: '#F7FAFC',
}

export default { COLORS };

// Other Component:
const color= 'PRIMARY';
const colorStyle = color && COLORS[color.toUpperCase()];
```

[A working example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgeQDIIEoGUBcNUFNQBOAJgDzQECWYA5gDQzlXUB8MAvDDAN4BQnAIgFEAYgEEAqkgAq2AOQBiAIwB2AEwAhACz9ZtPjAAKqAJIBZUagCac+QFZBawZt370gxADl+F6zAXDlMWE4FwBfHh5QSFhQABsQAg5ZIzMfWQBuSPBoGDiE9CgAT1jcdlyQeIIYADJq+GQ0dABtPIIAOigQcQAHbtwCOABDCFwACgBKAF1MqIgK3Db46lHWguLccfSgA).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best option is to have an enum matching the properties of that object you have, declaring keys as string is a loose solution that might allow you have a key that does not exist.

```
enum ColorOptions {
  DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT',
  PRIMARY = 'PRIMARY',
  SECONDARY = 'SECONDARY',
}
```

Than you can safely do it like

`const colorStyle = color && COLORS[ColorOptions.SECONDARY];`

full code:

```
const COLORS = {
  DEFAULT: '#172B4D',
  PRIMARY: '#5E72E4',
  SECONDARY: '#F7FAFC',
}

enum ColorOptions {
  DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT',
  PRIMARY = 'PRIMARY',
  SECONDARY = 'SECONDARY',
}
const color = ColorOptions.PRIMARY;
const colorStyle = color && COLORS[color];
console.log(colorStyle);
```

or even consider killing the COLOR object and have just an enum

```
export enum COLORS {
  DEFAULT = '#172B4D',
  PRIMARY = '#5E72E4',
  SECONDARY = '#F7FAFC',
}
console.log(colorStyle); // #5E72E4
```

or if your code is already validating `color` input and you just want to touch that line and shut TS you could:

```
const colorStyle = color && argonTheme.COLORS[color.toUpperCase() as keyof typeof COLORS];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a type for you for your COLORS , otherwise the any type would be set by default:

in your case its stringkey with string value , thus should look like

```
export default {
    const COLORS :{ [key: string]: string } =  {
      DEFAULT: '#172B4D',
      PRIMARY: '#5E72E4',
      SECONDARY: '#F7FAFC',
    }
};
```

Comment: Why provide duplicate answers?

Comment: @Titulum , could you explain where is the duplication here !!

Comment: We both tell the questioner to type the `COLORS` object. Our answers are nearly identical, the only difference is how the `COLORS` object is typed. But `Record<string, string>` and `{ [key: string]: string}` are both identical types, the only difference is that one is more verbose.

Comment: That the context of the answer hence the similarity , but not a duplication ;)